# Using content of a specific cell to determine in which folder an Excel spreadsheet is saved

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel template that I use to keep information about various clients.  These clients can be in various stages of the process such as "submitted", "pending", etc.  The status of the client will determine in which folder the information spreadsheet is saved (i.e., there's a folder for all "pending" clients, a folder for all "submitted" clients, etc.).  I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to write a Macro that could "read" information from a 'Status' cell and, depending on what was saved in that cell, save the Excel sheet to the correct folder?

Comment: Try recording a macro and editing it: post back with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: I have no idea where to start.  I've never done any coding or anything.  I was hoping someone here could have some pointers or starting points

Comment: Start here: [google search](https://www.google.com/search?{google:acceptedSuggestion}oq=excel+record+a+macro&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=excel+record+a+macro)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments: the macro recorder is the easiest way of learning the syntax of commands that you can use from the keyboard. However, I do not believe it will help here.

When the macro checks the status cell, it needs to close the client workbook (I assume it has already been saved) and then move it from its current folder to the new one.  I do not believe there is any way to get the macro recorder to record the statement that moves a file from one folder to another.

Small, easily written, macros can be used to perform a wide variety of tasks.  You need to have some pretty advanced requirements before Excel VBA will not be adequate.  I recommend everyone learns VBA.  Search the Internet for "Excel VBA Tutorial".  There are many tutorials and most are free.  Try a few then complete one that matches your learning style.  Alternatively, visit a good library or bookshop where you will find a selection of VBA primers.  I recommend visiting the library and trying a few primers before visiting the bookshop to buy the one most suited to your needs.  Learning VBA will not take too long and the investment in time will quickly repay itself.

Your macro will have to be in a master workbook which accesses and updates the client workbooks.  Many of the answers here show how to work with multiple workbooks.  Try a few search terms and I am sure you will find something that gets you started.

Look up "FileCopy Statement"  This is the simpliest way to copy a file from one folder to another. The Move method which involves use of FileSystemObjects is more complex but more flexible.

Good luck and welcome to the joys of programming.